# Angular 2 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material'

Tags: angular, material-design

I followed each steps described here: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

**Error I get**

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material' in '/Users/isabelle/my-project/src/app'
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts 14:0-51
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
```

**What I did**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-project
npm install --save @angular/material
```

**In src/app/app.module.ts**

```js
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
    
    // other imports 
@NgModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule],
    ...
})   
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I did that command again and everything ran smoothly

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Comment: This now gives me: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/a11y'`

Comment: As per updated Angular Material documentation, the `ng add @angular/material` command will install Angular Material, Component Dev Kit (CDK) and Angular Animations. Thus, it is a combination of various npm install commands for all of them separately.

Comment: @M M, Angular needs to update their docs pronto. Running the command ng add @angular/material won't install all those things which you said. Rather a run of these commands: npm i @angular/material --save and npm i @angular/cdk --save will definitely install ALL those pkgs. I have been there and i am currently have Angular v12.0.2 and Angular Material 12 running on my pc.

Answer (score 19):

```
npm install --save @angular/material

npm install --save @angular/cdk
```

restart dev server

(usually the console will tell you when there are dependencies, pay attention to it)

Answer (score 3):

Simply add it to your project

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete *node_modules* and run *npm install*.

Answer (score 1):

**first try only this command**

1. npm install --save @angular/material

**OR**
**if not work then**

1. npm install --save @angular/material
2. npm install --save @angular/cdk

Answer (score 1):

install angular material

```
npm install @angular/material
```

check and edit yuor imports component...
for example:

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing latest version of rxjs using following commands
npm install rxjs @latest

Comment: How does this solve the problem better that the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

after running this command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

I get error

> Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/a11y'

then I restart my application and all OK

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I was building the project from the scratch. For me what I did wrong is I was trying to run

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Before running the

```
npm install
```

Command

Once I ran the "npm install" first and then tried to install materials, everything started to install properly without any issues. Its a very silly basic mistake which is worth to note for beginers like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete Your node_modules folder and package.lock.json file manually  and then        `npm install`   if not work then   `ng add@angular/material`